# Can rdiff do incremental backups

Tags: rdiff-backup

I am new to ubuntu , i have installed rdiff-backup.

I have folder called   `sqlfiles` on remote ftp server.The sql filesa are stored for last three days and then deleted. But i want to download the all copies to local computers

I want to have incremental backups on my local server so that

1)`If file is same then it should not be copied`
2)`if different , then overwrite it`
3)`If file is in local directory and not in FTP , then leave as it is`

How can i apply those rules to r-diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 of your requirements can be done with `rsync` already.

```
1. Default behavior.
2. Default behavior.
3. --existing (Transfer only files that already exist on the destination host.)
```

Comment: how can i enter passowrd of remote shh in rsync command

Comment: you can use `rsync --rsh='ssh'`, so your command would look something likethis:  `rsync --rsh='ssh' -a --progress --existing --dry-run /dir/to/upload/from/ user@server:/dir/to/upload/to/`. You can remove `--dry-run` and `--progress` later. pay attention to the `/` after `/dir/to/upload/from/` it will upload the **contents** of that directory, not directory itself. if you would like to upload the whole directory instead, remove trailing `/`